# in ubuntu18.04 in a docker container can vncserver take the password and reply to "view"only on command line

Tags: docker, tightvncserver

this for a non-interactive automated startup from the docker file `ENTRYPOINT`

something like `vncserver --password 'aPassWord'` or by setting environment variables or preloading a config file etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the vncpasswd utility in "filter" mode

```
echo aPassword | vncpasswd > $HOME/.vnc/passwd
chmod 400 $HOME/.vnc/passwd
```